# How to modify class with singleton scope (Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, singleton

Let say I'm trying to remove a object which is stored in hashmap of ClassA. ClassB is a static class which has a destroy method to remove required object from hashmap.  Even after removing it, later when I tried to remove another object, i see old element which was removed before still exist. Is there something I'm missing?

```
@Named
@Scope
public class ClassA implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<String, ModelObject> modelObjects = new HashMap<String, ModelObject>();

    public synchronized void addMo(ModelObject modelObject) {
        modelObjects.put(modelObject.getUuid(), modelObject);
    }

    public synchronized ModelObject updateMo(ModelObject modelObject) {
        return modelObjects.put(modelObject.getUuid(), modelObject);
    }

    public synchronized void removeMo(ModelObject modelObject) {
        modelObjects.remove(modelObject.getUuid());
    }

    public synchronized void removeMo(String modelObjectId) {
        modelObjects.remove(modelObjectId);
    }

    public ModelObject getMo(String uuid) {
        return modelObjects.get(uuid);
    }
}
```

`ClassB` is

```
public class ClassB{

    private static ClassA manager;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void setmanager(ClassA manager) {
        ClassB.manager = manager;
    }
    public static synchronized void destoryMo(String modelObjectID) {
        // get ClassA bean
        if (manager == null) {
            LOG.error("Managed bean ClassA not found (null) ==> no modelObject update!");
        }
        ModelObject wb = manager.getMo(modelObjectID);
        if(wb != null){
            wb.removeAllCache();
            wb = null;
            manager.removeMo(modelObjectID);
        }
        LOG.info("Destroyed ModelObject with modelObject id :" + modelObjectID);

    }
}
```

Comment: how and where do you verify that the old object still exists? are you trying to remove the old object again? with the same modelObjectID?

Comment: please post the unit test that failes.